# Объекты не добавляются в базу данных mongoDB. Локально все работает, а на ВМ - нет

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, express

При регистрации в приложении объект с данными пользователя не попадает в БД, хотя fecth запрос уходит и регистрация и авторизация проходят успешно. Объект с карточкой фильма так же не добавляется в бд, хотя ответ от сервера 201 created. Но локально все работает.

Comment: вам бы почитать справку о том как задавать вопрос